# update field or redirect page using jquery and asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Im new to jquery and stuck with what i want to achieve.
Heres what I want to do using jquery and asp.net mvc.

- click a submit button
- this calls an action method called LogOn in the controller Account
- if the call allows users to log in succesfully redirect to a url (sepecified by LogOn)
- if it fails replace a div(with id="error") with "sorry error occured"

so far I tried this:

```
 $("#submit")
            .button()
            .click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Account/LogOn",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data, textStatus) {
                        if (data.redirect) {
                            // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
                            window.location.href = data.redirect;
                        }
                        else {
                            // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
                            $("#error2").replaceWith(data.error);
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
```

how do I construct the relevant bits in the action method? to make this work?
and is the jquery code ok? i suspect prob not.

Thanks

Comment: Just a comment, don't show error if its not an error. That's making your system looking ugly and unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect asp.net page at same directory , you can by Jquery/Java script by this :

```
  $("#ctl00_iframecontent_BtnCancle").click(function () {
        window.location = "IncSLAList.aspx?bi=37";
    });
```

and 
To redirect to Another page of project , can use :

```
     window.location.href = "http://ImageUpload/Welcome.aspx?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery is almost correct:

- Don't call `.button()` (unless you're using jQuery UI and want to do that)
- Add `return false;` at the end of the `click` handler to prevent the browser from submitting normally.

In the action, you would either `return Json(new { redirect = str })` or `return Json(new { error = str })`.

Comment: I've updated the action method with jsonResult, but not sure about the jquery, can you give the example similar to mine? Am i meant to pass a data field?

Comment: Im getting somewhere, but ModelState.IsValid is false in my Action method, am I meant to do anything else?

Comment: @rakos: You need to pass `data` as well.